# R^2 is negative when I split train and test set in Lasso Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, lasso-regression

I tried running the Lasso Regression with Crude oil price, I can't shuffle the train and test set when I split into train and test set

Crude Oil Price in 2020, it's very strange because of COVID-19

But I want to know how to fix the error on train and test set, I need to use this with no shuffle

```
# Import Libraries

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline 
plt.style.use('ggplot') 
import warnings; warnings.simplefilter('ignore')

# Read data from CSV to Pandas 
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.kaggle.com/yothinpukongnin/crude-oil-price?select=DB_2.csv
', index_col=0)
#df = df.iloc[ 0:108 , : ]
X = df.drop(['Dubai','EU_RUB'], axis=1)
y = df['Dubai']

# Split Train and Test Set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=7, shuffle = False)

#Lasso Regression 
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
reg = Lasso(alpha=0.5)
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

#R^esults from traditional Lasso
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
print('Lasso Regression: R^2 score on training set', reg.score(X_train, y_train)*100)
print('Lasso Regression: R^2 score on test set', reg.score(X_test, y_test)*100)
```

R square for test set = -356

Comment: Fix what error? You do not report any error.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you are asking about the negative R^2 score.

This however is no error in the strict sense - [R^2 score can be arbitrarily negative](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html). It just means that your model does not perform well, actually it performs even worse than the model that would always predict the average value (that one would get R^2 score equal to 0).

Although it is producing a bad model, your code works technically correctly. Also the problem of the negative R^2 score is not directly connected to the splitting of the dataset to the train and test parts.

How exactly to make a better model is too complex a question to be answered here. Just a few hints (so that you know what topics to look for):

- your dataset is very small with relatively many features so your model very probably overfits (supported also by a good training R^2 score) - learn how to diagnose and mitigate problems with over- and underfitting and the bias vs. variance trade-off,
- this is a time-series problem and should be dealt as such - read something about specifics of machine learning prediction for time-series data,
- you should preprocess your data before fitting any model (this possibly includes but is not limited to normalization/standardization, feature encoding, feature generation, dimensionality reduction, adding external data, time series specific preprocessing, ...)
- you should try more different models and grid-search for the best hyperparameters.

Of course there is much more than this and if you are new to machine learning, it would be a good idea to read an introductory book or take a course so that you get a basic overview and a starting point for a further study. For example [this is an excelent course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning).